# SQL Server: select MAX Value when LEFT JOIN and then populate the column in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, max, aggregate-functions

I have two tables `Response` and `Distributions`:

[Table structure with expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYcNa.png)

In this case, there are multiple responses but 1 distribution. We need to tie just one latest response before the assignment date to the distribution, basically

```
MAX(COALESCE(RESPONSE_DATE, CREATED_DATE)) <= ASSIGNMENT_DATE
```

The SQL query I tried:

```
SELECT 
    resp.CONTACT_ID, resp.RESPONSE_ID, resp.RESPONSE_DATE, 
    resp.CREATED_DATE, d.ASSIGNMENT_DATE AS DISTRIBUTION_DATE
FROM 
    Response resp
LEFT JOIN 
    Distribution d ON resp.CONTACT_ID = d.CONTACT_ID
-- 12 Hour Grace Period For assignments created before response
                   AND DATEADD(hour, -12, COALESCE(resp.RESPONSE_DATE, resp.CREATED_DATE)) <= d.ASSIGNMENT_DATE
```

This query returns `DISTRIBUTION_DATE` as 2020-10-28 for first two rows when.

This condition

```
DATEADD(hour, -12, COALESCE(resp.RESPONSE_DATE, resp.CREATED_DATE)) <= ASSIGNMENT_DATE
```

is satisfied (see SQL query returning wrong output table in the attached screenshot).

However, I want `DISTRIBUTION_DATE` as "2020-10-28" only for the second row as shown in the expected output. The reason is the latest response just before the assignment date will get distributed and I don't care about initial X responses (We should tie one distribution to only one latest response)

I tried to use

```
MAX(DATEADD(hour, -12, COALESCE(resp.RESPONSE_DATE, resp.CREATED_DATE))) <= ASSIGNMENT_DATE
```

in the `JOIN ON` condition but that doesn't work in SQL.

Please let me know how to structure the query and get the expected output.

**NOTE:** The join from `Response` to `Distribution` has to be on `CONTACT_ID`, there is no explicit `JOIN_KEY` and it can lead to 1:M joins as we have same `CONTACT_ID` (that's the reason a lot of filtering is done in join ON condition), ideal scenario is to have `RESPONSE_ID` on `Distribution` table as well but that's not how the data is structured.

TIA

Comment: Sample data and expected output (as text) would help immensely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you require, you'll need to run a query like this to get the expected results:

```
SELECT CONTACT_ID, RESPONSE_ID, RESPONSE_DATE, CREATED_DATE, CASE WHEN RANKING = 1 THEN DISTRIBUTION_DATE ELSE NULL END AS DISTRIBUTION_DATE
FROM (
    SELECT 
        resp.CONTACT_ID, resp.RESPONSE_ID, resp.RESPONSE_DATE, 
        resp.CREATED_DATE, d.ASSIGNMENT_DATE AS DISTRIBUTION_DATE,
        DATEADD(hour, -12, COALESCE(resp.RESPONSE_DATE, resp.CREATED_DATE)) AS GRACE_DATE,
        RANK() OVER (
        PARTITION BY resp.CONTACT_ID
        ORDER BY 
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEADD(hour, -12, COALESCE(resp.RESPONSE_DATE, resp.CREATED_DATE)) <= d.ASSIGNMENT_DATE
                    THEN DATEADD(hour, -12, COALESCE(resp.RESPONSE_DATE, resp.CREATED_DATE))
                ELSE 
                    '19000101'
            END
        DESC ) AS RANKING
    FROM 
        Response resp
    LEFT JOIN 
        [Distribution] d ON resp.CONTACT_ID = d.CONTACT_ID
) DerivedTable
ORDER BY CONTACT_ID, RESPONSE_ID
```

Basically, I use a rank to workout the closest date based on the assignment date, and then know that the ranking where it is 1 should be the one to show the distribution date.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the response date can be null which is why you are using COALESCE.

The following query will return the last response whose date is less than assignment date.

```
SELECT  d.*, r.*
FROM    [dbo].[Response] r
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Distribution] d
            ON  r.CONTACT_ID = d.CONTACT_ID
WHERE   COALESCE(r.[RESPONSE_DATE],[CREATED_DATE]) =
        (
            SELECT  MAX(COALESCE(rr.[RESPONSE_DATE],rr.[CREATED_DATE]))
            FROM    [dbo].[Response] rr
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Distribution] dd
                        ON  rr.CONTACT_ID = dd.CONTACT_ID
            WHERE   COALESCE(rr.[RESPONSE_DATE],rr.[CREATED_DATE]) < dd.ASSIGNMENT_DATE
            AND     rr.CONTACT_ID = r.CONTACT_ID
        )
```

It may be possible to simplify this but it will return what you need. Also if there are two responses with the same date, both will be returned.